# How to catch or sync props value between child and parent component?

Tags: vue-component, vue-props

Currently I'm working on vuejs 3 and I developed my own datatable component and it's working fine. Now I'm just trying to extend this data table with one more feature that is, dynamically I would like to add a "status column" where a props value will be updated based on condition and that updated props value I would like to catch in my child component.

Child component code:

```
<data-table
  :rows="state.rows"
  :columns="state.columns"
  :num_to_show="state.num_to_show"
  styleClass="tableOne vgt-table"
> 
  // Below code passing to parent component and want to get back calculated 
  props(progress_val) value from parent
  <template #progress-bar >
    <progress-bar :progress="progress_val">
    </progress-bar>
  </template> 
</data-table>
```

Parent Component code:

// Here progress_val calculating correctly and this value would like to catch in
child component

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, just updated my code like below:
//In below code received the returned props

```
<template #progress-bar="{progress_val, color}" >      
    <progress-bar :progress="progress_val" :color="color">
    </progress-bar>
</template>
```